# Obtener control de un CONTROL IMAGEVIEW

Tags: java, android

Actualmente tengo un menú que es un `NavigationView`. Donde este se compone del `header` y del `body` , en el `HEADER` tengo un **imagen** , que es la siguiente

```
<ImageView

        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="5sp"
        android:maxHeight="10sp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

        android:id="@+id/foto_gallery"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />
```

Ahora me gustaría poder que el usuario la cambie por lo que lo dejo seleccionar una de su galería y guardo esa url en una base de datos Sql lite , hasta acá todo bien , pero a la hora de querer referencia la imagen pensé que con buscarla con su ID

```
foto_gallery = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.foto_gallery);
```

Iba a ser suficiente pero me encuentro que al buscarla por ID es como si tomara que tengo un `imagenview` en mi `Layout` de mi clase , pero no es así esta en un `xml` que forma parte del `NaviewView` , entonces como puedo   hacer  para referenciar a esa imagen que esta en un `xml` que forma parte de mi menú , no se si me di a entender, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza el metodo `navigationView.getHeaderView(int index)` para obtener la referencia de la cabecera y luego buscas la imagen utilizando `findViewById()`:

```
ImageView profile = (ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.foto_gallery);
```

Comment: gracias Einer siempre atento alas respuestas . y haciendo esta comunidad tan acogedora ,

Comment: Paso a molestar Einer pero mi foto esta en un xml que se llama nav_header_main , y intente hacerlo asi  ImageView profile = (ImageView) R.layout.nav_header_main.findViewById(R.id.foto_gallery); pero nose da error no entiendi bien tu ejemplo disculpa soy medio noob

Comment: En mi ejemplo no esta `(ImageView) R.layout.nav_header_main.findViewById(R.id.foto_gallery)`. Seguro que estas haciendo como esta en la respuesta?

Comment: Fijate que esta `(ImageView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0)` no `(ImageView) R.layout.nav_header_main.findViewById(R.id.foto_gallery)`.

Comment: si lo utilizo asi , no reconoce navigationView me dice que esa variable no existe ni puedo traer la referencia de nada

Comment: Claro claro. Edita tu pregunta y agregara el contenido de la clase o busca un variable que sea del tipo `NavigationView` y reemplazala por esa. Lo que pasa es que interprete que el objeto del `NavigationView` se llamaria `navigationView` ya que android lo nombra asi por defecto.

Comment: ah , ya encontre jaja , gracias !